# What is the fastest way to check if a substring is in a string as an entire word or term, like RegEx with boundaries?

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, contains

I have a problem to find the fastest way to check if a substring is in a string as an entire word or term. Currently, I'm using RegEx, but I need to perform thousands of verifications and RegEx is being VERY slow.

There are many ways to respond to this. The easier way to verify is `substring in string`:

```
substring = "programming"
string = "Python is a high-level programming language"

substring in string

>>> True
```

In other hand, it's a naivy solution when we need to find the substring as an entire word or term:

```
substring = "program"
string = "Python is a high-level programming language"

substring in string

>>> True
```

Another solution is to split the string into a list of words and verify if the substring is in that list:

```
substring = "program"
string = "Python is a high-level programming language"

substring in string.split()

>>> False
```

Nevertheless, it doesn't work if the substring is a term. To resolve this, another solution would be to use RegEx:

```
import re

substring = "high-level program"
string = "Python is a high-level programming language"

re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(substring), string) != None

>>> False
```

However, my biggest problem is that the solution is REALLY slow if you need to perform thousands of verifications.

To mitigate this issue, I created some approaches that, although they are faster than RegEx (for the use I need), still are a lot slower than `substring in string`:

```
substring = "high-level program"
string = "Python is a high-level programming language"

all([word in string.split() for word in substring.split()])

>>> False
```

Although simple, the above approach didn't fit because it ignores substring word order, returning `True` if the substring was `"programming high-level"`, unlike the solution in RegEx. So, I created another approach verifying if the substring is in a ngram list where each ngram has the same number of words as the substring:

```
from nltk import ngrams

substring = "high-level program"
string = "Python is a high-level programming language"

ngram = list(ngrams(string.split(), len(substring.split())))

substring in [" ".join(tuples) for tuples in ngram]

>>> False
```

**EDIT:** Here is a less slow version, working with the same principle, but using only built-in functions:

```
substring = "high-level program"
string = "Python is a high-level programming language"

length = len(substring.split())
words = string.split()
ngrams = [" ".join(words[i:i+length]) for i in range(len(words) - length)]

substring in ngrams

>>> False
```

Someone knows some a faster approach to find a substring inside a string as an entire word or term?

Comment: Although *"high-level program"* is in *"Python is a high-level programming language"* if you compare character by character, I need a fast function that, in this case, returns `False` because *"high-level program"* not in *"Python is a high-level programming language"* **as an entire word or term**. I presented some solutions in my question, but they're very slow for bulk use.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through the string and splice the string according to the substring length and compare the splice string with the substring if it is equal return True.

**Illustration***

```
strs = "Coding"
substr = "ding"
slen = 4
i = 0

check = strs[i:slen+i]==substr

# 1st iteration
strs[0:4+0] == ding
codi == ding # False

# 2nd iteration
i=1
strs[1:4+1] == ding
odin == ding # False

# 3rd iteration
i=2
strs [2:4+2] == ding
ding == ding # True
```

**Solution**

```py
def str_exist(string, substring, slen):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i:slen+i] == substring:
             return True
    return False

substring = "high-level program"
string = "Python is a high-level programming language"
slen = len(substring)

print(str_exist(string, substring, slen))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
```

Comment: `high-level program` is not present in the source string _as a complete word or term_.  Did you read the question?

Comment: I know please try this solution and see

Comment: This ain't O(n). You aren't going through every character of the string once.

Comment: @Maya Yes I am looping through the whole string once so the time complexity is O(n).

Comment: Check the inner condition. String[a:b] isn't a constant time operation.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. I've added comments in my code for better understanding of what this algorithm is doing.

```py
def check_substr(S: str, sub_str: str) -> bool:
  """
  This function tells whether the given sub-string 
  in a string is present or not.
  
  Parameters
  S:       str: The original string
  sub_str: str: The sub-string to be checked
  
  Returns
  result: boolean: Whether the string is present or not
  """
  i = 0
  pointer = 0
  
  while (i < len(S)):
    # This means that we are already in that word
    # whose sub-part is already matched. For eg:
    # `program` in `programming`. Therefore we are
    # going to skip the rest of the word and check
    # the next word instead.
    if (S[i] != ' ' and pointer == len(sub_str)):
      while (i < len(S) and S[i] != ' '):
        i += 1
      i += 1
      pointer = 0
      
      if (i >= len(S)):
        break
    
    # If we encounter a space, we check whether we
    # have already found the sub-string or not.
    elif (S[i] == ' ' and pointer == len(sub_str)):
      break
      
    if (S[i] == sub_str[pointer]):
      pointer += 1
      
    else:
      # If the current element of the original 
      # string matched with the first element of
      # the sub-string then we increment the 
      # pointer by 1. Otherwise we set it to 0.
      pointer = 1 if (S[i] == sub_str[0]) else 0
      
    i += 1
  
  return pointer == len(sub_str)
  
S = "Python is a high-level programming"
print(check_substr(S, "high-level program"))
print(check_substr(S, "programming language"))
```

### Output

```
False
False
```

### Time Complexity

```
O(n)
```

#### Edits:

As @PGHE pointed out in the comments, we can also do the checking in punctuation characters and not only in spaces. Since the OP hasn't mentioned anything about the punctuation, I'm keeping this answer as it is.

Comment: This not what the user asking for please read the question again. "program" should return True not False because "program" is in "programming"

Comment: @Eduardo Ramon Resser could you please confirm this? Since this is not an entire word or term so shouldn't this return False?

Comment: I appreciate it's not in the original question, but will this stay O(n) if you check the word/term ends at punction character not just a space?

Comment: I hope so. Because as the number of punctuation characters are fixed let's say p and for every iteration you have to do atmost p checks. Since p is a constant number and does not depend on n (string length), therefore the order will be O(pn) = O(n)

Comment: In the above code, you can just make a tuple of punctuations and use the `in` operator. @PGHE

Comment: You're right @Maya. I need a function that returns true only if a substring is in a string *as an entire word or term*. The strings that I need to implement this function don't have punctuations, so, it's all right. Nevertheless, I tested these function, but it doesn't work if the substring is found at the end of string, but not as an entire word or term, where instead return *False*, it raises an error. E.g. `substring = "high-level program"` and `string = "Python is a high-level programming"`. I changed the function, to resolve this issue, but there were no changes in speed.

Comment: @EduardoRamonResser could you please run this once and let me know. I added the string out-of-bound checking in the inner while loop. It would be also nice if you can provide some more details on your original problem. Maybe it can be done in some other way.

Comment: @Maya the function ran, but still without an improvement in speed. My implementation consists in classify thousands of terms by relevant ngram clusters (independent if the terms are in more than one cluster).

Comment: @Maya I have a list of all terms (in my case, there are 4,186), where I process them to `generalized_terms` so I have another function that generates `all_ngrams` (all sizes) from these terms (in my case was generated 10,307). Furthermore, I must create another 2 lists: `generalized_terms_per_ngram`, formed by another lists that contain each term in *all_ngrams* and `ngrams_per_generalized_group`, formed by all ngrams based on each list in *generalized_terms_per_ngram*. This whole process takes a maximum of 10 sec in Google Colab.

Comment: @Maya The problem is after, because my objective is, `for idx, generalized_terms in enumerate(generalized_terms_per_ngram)`, to know the most frequent ngrams from each list of terms (that, sometimes, may differ from `ngrams_per_generalized_group`, and, based in another conditions, I can rename or delete this ngram), so, the list that takes more time to create is `matches_per_ngram = [ngram in term for term in generalized_terms]) for ngram in ngrams_per_generalized_group[idx]]`.

Comment: @Maya Using `ngram in term`, it takes reasonable 1 minute, but I need to perform the search as an entire word or term. Using RegEx, it took more than 10 minutes and in the approaches presented in these question takes 8 minutes. If I repeat this process in lists > 15k terms it can take hours.

Answer (score 1):

Add spaces on both sides of the substring and string, then test 'substring in string'